# Flask equivalent for @Html.Action in Mvc

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have an Mvc app page which has a list of settings and a form to enter new settings and also to edit them.  How do I render the list as well as the form In the same request. As for Asp.net Mvc I will have the request processing the form and list will be called via `@Html.Action` which will call a method in controller that returns. `PartialViewResult`?

What is the best way to achieve this in `Flask`? I think `Include` is more of `RenderPartial`..

Answer (score 1):

Using Jinja2, the best way is use the {% include "_partial.html" %}. It will be render at server on page loading.
This function works even if include an html file from other blueprint( if you using blueprints).

If you want to update dynamically You should use Ajax to do it.

Comment: Hi but this will render the partial.html file. But what I want is to call a function from codebehind and render a partial template.

Comment: I didn't find a way to render partial without submitting the page and refresh, or you can do it via javascript and populate with the response(the response can be an html script, and you append to wherever you want).